# How to delete SQLite database table in android java

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am using the following code for deleting SQLite database table. Apparently, there is a message that the table has been deleted, but when the app is run again, the table is shown again.

ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.java

```
    private String r(String s, String str, String s1) {
this.s = s;
this.str = str;
this.s1 = s1;
return str;
}

 public void deleteGroupData(String str) {
this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, r("contact_group_id='", str, "'"), (String[]) null);
 }
```

GroupDetailsDbAdapter.java

```
        public boolean deleteData(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = this.mDb;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("group_id=");
    sb.append(str);
    return sQLiteDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, sb.toString(), 
(String[]) null) > 0;
}
```

ContactsList.java

```
   button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    GroupDetailsDbAdapter groupDetailsDbAdapter = new 
   GroupDetailsDbAdapter(ContactsList.this);
    groupDetailsDbAdapter.open();
    groupDetailsDbAdapter.deleteData(str);
    groupDetailsDbAdapter.close();
    ContactsDetailsDbAdapter contactsDetailsDbAdapter = new 
    ContactsDetailsDbAdapter(ContactsList.this);
    contactsDetailsDbAdapter.open();
    contactsDetailsDbAdapter.deleteGroupData(str);
    contactsDetailsDbAdapter.close();
    dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ContactsList.this.finish();
    return true;
   }
  });
```

While following error is being shown in Logcat. Can someone please check this code and tell me what is the error?

[image]

Comment: That "table deleted" toast is printed by you irrespective of the actual result of the delete. Check the returned int value of db.delete() to know if it's deleted. Cross check your query

Comment: after click on delete did you check inside the app inspection you table was delete or not?

Comment: There is another activity in my app which loads the tables from the database and shows them in the spinner, then the table which we have deleted is shown there.

Answer (score 0):

The [delete convenience method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) says :-

> Convenience method for **deleting rows** in the database.

A table is a container of rows (0 to n rows). Deleting all rows will result in the table still existing but empty.

You need to **DROP** the table. There is no convenience method for doing so. You need to use the `execSQL` method to invoke the drop SQL.

e.g. `sQLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + ";");` instead of `return sQLiteDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, sb.toString(),  (String[]) null) > 0;`. But see the note below about `execSQL` not returning any values.

as per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)

- `IF EXISTS`  means that if the table does not exist there will be no failure.
- `execSQL` does not return any values, so you would need to either not return anything or ascertain the suitable value to return.

So perhaps use:-

```
public deleteData(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = this.mDb;
    sQLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + ";");
}
```

- note no value returned

or:-

```
public boolean deleteData(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = this.mDb;
    sQLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + ";");
    return true;
}
```

- unlike the convenience `delete` which includes extraction of the number of rows deleted. Deleting (**DROP**ing) a table has no such results. Hence there is no value to return. If you wanted an indication as to whether or not the table was dropped then you would have to check to see if it existed prior to the delete or use drop without IF EXISTS and handle the exception if the table does not exist.

Comment: Can you explain with a example? Please

Comment: @Maria amended the answer

Comment: Ok! but how to convert it to >>>       public boolean deleteData(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = this.mDb;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("group_id=");
    sb.append(str);
    return sQLiteDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, sb.toString(), 
(String[]) null) > 0;
}

Comment: When i use this code as you suggest App Crashes every time.      public boolean deleteData(String str) {
        SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = this.mDb;
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + ";") ;
        return true;
    }

Comment: @Maria Probably because, contrary to your question, you do not really want to delete the table but you want to delete some rows, as you were doing,  and that * the table is shown again.* is because you are not refreshing the data for the adapter that is behind the List, so the list is showing old data that was extracted before the rows were deleted.

Comment: I already used .notifyDataSetChanged(); . But every time app crash and not open again unless i uninstalled it and installed again.